# Scrolling a list to a specific item in ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

In ionic 2 beta 6 I'm trying to scroll to a specific card in a list of cards:

```
<ion-card  *ngFor="#item of items" [attr.id]="item.name" >
```

To do this i'm using the lifecycle hook onPageDidEnter, so that I will scrollTop when the page has fully entered ( as [per the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/)). My code looks like this:

```
onPageDidEnter() {

  var el = document.getElementById(this.currentItem);
  if (el !== null) {
    el.scrollTop=0;
  }
}
```

When I debug I can see how the view scrolls to the item right after `el.scrollTop=0` but when I continue execution, somehow the view returns to the top and refuses to stay in the current item.

I have also tried several other angular 2 and ionic 2 hooks, but the behaviour remains the same; is there something I'm not seeing here?

Comment: Sounds like you're changing the position too early and something resets it afterwards. Have you checked the `scrollTo` from http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/ ?